# In LaTeX, how to have a TextField with limited number of characters

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I am using LaTeX to make a fillable PDF file.

I use the `\TextField` command in the `hyperref` package to get the fillable field in the PDF file.

In some places, I want to have a field which has a limited number of characters for input, e.g. the phone number or card number.

How could I realize this effect?  I looked up the `texdoc` for `hyperref` package but failed to find any information for this effect.

Would anyone please give me some idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides the key-value `maxlen` that limits the number of characters in a text field:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=phonenumber,value=xxxyyyzzzz,maxlen=10]{Phone:}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This is discussed in the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) under section [**6.2 Forms optional parameters**](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-220006.2).

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner.  Your answer has definitely solved my problem.

I am sorry for my inattention when reading the manual, though I had gone through the option arguments in §6.2.

Comment: @HanzhiDiao: [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) has many options that are not readily documented. If this answered your question, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Comment: I have made the accepting.  Sorry for the delayed operation.  It is my first post here.